# How to set allow_url_include On in MAMP mac OSX?

Tags: apache, mamp

If i set allow_url_include = On or allow_url_include=1 in MAMP/conf/php5.6.7/php.ini 
configuration not change, and in phpinfo() allow_url_include is set Off.
After i restart MAMP.

How to set it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open PHP.ini in
File > Edit Template > PHP > PHP x.xx.xx php.ini

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIXos.png)

Then under allow_url_fopen = On add allow_url_include = On